# Ways to avoid memory bloat in rails when instantiating a large number of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory

I have a Ruby on Rails application that loads thousands of map markers and displays them on a map using the Google Maps API.  All of the markers are necessary in the view, so they must be loaded by the controller and displayed.

Consequentially, I am allocating large amounts of memory each time a user loads their map and thus am running into "R14 - Memory Quota Exceeded in Ruby (MRI)" errors in Heroku quite frequently as I go over the 500MB memory limit.

I have optimized my code by using less data intensive queries, such as using:

```
@user.markers.select(:coordinates)
```

as opposed to:

```
@user.markers
```

Yet I am still instantiating a lot of memory due to the raw number of objects I'm loading (sometimes in excess of 2,000 - 3,000 on a map per user.) With multiple users making similar requests, I quickly rack up over 500MB of memory.

Does this mean that I simply need to allocate more memory to my Heroku instance or are there any other ways of reducing memory usage for a situation such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `pluck` instead of `select`, that won't give you objects, just the fields in an array. That should help your memory situation. [Check out the docs for more info](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck).

Comment: Thanks @dwhite I used pluck and saved some memory, I appreciate that suggestion.  That said, I'm still adding ~70MB each map request even when plucking to reduce memory footprint.  Solution may just be to up my plan to get more RAM from Heroku.